# How insert data into res.render function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying use data from the user 'User' object into the res.render() function.
It is not working. Any ideas
I have the following code:

```
var express = require("express"), 
    app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));

var User = {
    firstname: "FirstNameExample",
    lastname: "LastNameExample",
    role: "Site Admin",
    permissions: [
        {
            All: "True"
        }
    ]
}

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('pages/home', { 'data': User });
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function(err){
    (err) ? console.log(err) : console.log('App Started on Port 3000');
});
```

The error in the console is:
at Object. (/location/app.js:22:18)

Comment: what's the error you are getting ?

Comment: at Object.<anonymous> at Object. (/location/app.js:22:18)

Comment: How are you trying to access data in your view? Btw, you don't need quotations around `data` key.

Comment: I've tried: <%= data.User.firstname %> 
and without data: <%= User.firstname %>

Comment: Have you tried <%= data.firstname %> ?

Answer (score 3):

> I've tried: <%= data.User.firstname %> and without data: <%=
>   User.firstname %>

`data` is reference to `User` object. Try this:

```
<%= data.firstname %>
```